# How to know if someone is accessing my computer remotly?

Tags: windows-10, security, remote-access

Lately I noticed wired stuff in my computer like files disappearing, a restart without a reason no warning or notification just restarted suddenly, so I thought maybe someone is assessing my computer remotely than I checked the event log it haven't been logged the file disappearence and the restart, also when I opened the task manager the cpu usage is high after 1 second at most the usage drops and the application list change, so how do I make sure that my computer is being accessed remotely and how I prevent it from happening again and if is possible I want to know who is accessing it.

Note I have kaspersky installed but before I install it I used the computer With out anti virus.

Comment: I yet have to see a "is somebody hacking me" question that doesn't get answered with "no". CPU spikes when opening Task Manager for everyone using Windows at least since XP, that's how it works. Application list changes because it's refreshing every second. You haven't used the computer without an antivirus, Windows 10 has Defender built in. We could try to find out why your computer restarted and where are your files, but that's [material for a different question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/267029)

Answer (score -1):

Download antivirus, alot of them have backdoor detection tools.
What these tools will do is analyse network traffic and see what application is sending/receiving. With this information you can find the application in question, look it up if you have to. If it's a strange one and isn't a known process.  it's probable there is malware malware or a backdoor in there.  here is some resources instead of just dismissing you like most people do online:
https://www.2-spyware.com/backdoors-removal
https://www.malwarebytes.com/backdoor/
Most Antivirus Will remove these and you should be fine afterwards.